How can I ensure alerts are triggered consistently whenever pods enter a Failed or CrashLoopBackOff state using Grafana and Prometheus?
I have configured an alert in Grafana and Prometheus to trigger when pods are in a Failed or CrashLoopBackOff state, but it’s not working as expected. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it.
My Json Configured:
  "alert": "KubernetesPodIsCrashLooping",
  "expr": "rate(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[5m]) > 0 and on(pod, namespace) kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason{reason=\"CrashLoopBackOff\"} > 0",
  "for": "1m",
  "labels": {
    "eventType": "5",
    "host": "{{$labels.pod}}",
    "id": "330201",
    "namespace": "{{$labels.namespace}}",
    "name": "Kubernetes Pod {{$labels.namespace}}/{{$labels.pod}} Is Crash Looping",
    "text": "KubernetesPodIsCrashLooping",
    "source": "CPRO",
    "severity": "CRITICAL",
    "probableCause": "0"
  },
  "annotations": {
    "description": "Kubernetes Pod {{$labels.namespace}}/{{$labels.pod}} is crash looping.",
    "summary": "Crash looping detected in Kubernetes Pod {{$labels.namespace}}/{{$labels.pod}}."
  }
}






Take your query and run directly in Prometheus or Grafana Explore. Alert will be triggered where you see spans of at least minute length with results present.
